# How to correctly use SQL joins/subqueries in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy, subquery

Say I have the following SQL code and I want to change it to Sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT amount FROM table1
JOIN table2 
  ON table2.id = table1.b_id
JOIN (SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE val1 = %s AND val2 = %s) inst
  ON inst.id = table1.i_id
WHERE
  val3 = %s
```

I've tried making a subquery for the SELECT id FROM table3 clause as follows:

```
subq = session.query(table3.id).filter(and_(table3.val1 == 'value', table3.val2 == 'value')).subquery()
```

And then putting everything together:

```
query = session.query(table1).join(table2).filter(table2.id == table1.b_id).\
join(subq).filter(table1.val3 == 'value')
```

When I ouput query.first().amount, this works for a few examples, but for some queries I'm getting no results when there should be something there, so I must be messing up somewhere. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: What does the returned SQL statement look like? Can you given and example of when it does and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Query below should produce exactly the `SQL` you have. It is not much different from your, but removes some unnecessary things.
So if it does not work, then also your original `SQL` might not work. Therefore, I assume that your issue is not `SQL` but either data or the parameters for that query. And you can always print out the query itself by `engine.echo = True`.

```
val1, val2, val3 = 'value', 'value', 'value'  # @NOTE: specify filter values
subq = (session.query(table3.id)
        .filter(and_(table3.val1 == val1, table3.val2 == val2))
        ).subquery(name='inst')

quer = (
    session.query(table1.amount)  # @NOTE: select only one column
    .join(table2)  # @NOTE: no need for filter(...)
    .join(subq)
    .filter(table1.val3 == val3)
).first()

print(quer and quer.amount)
```